# how can we set the background color of html editor using ajax color picker extender in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

this is my code,i have to change the background color of html editor using ajax color picker extender
code is here..

```
<CC:HtmlEditor ID="PublicBodyEditor" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="820px" style="margin: 60px 0;"/>
 <asp:TextBox ID="BodyColor" runat="server" Columns="7" MaxLength="7"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
 <asp:Label ID="sampleBodyColor" runat="server" Width="20"  Height="20" Text=" "></asp:Label>
                    <ajax:ColorPickerExtender ID="BodyPick" 
                        runat="server" 
                        TargetControlID="BodyColor" 
                        SampleControlID="sampleBodyColor"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery like this
$("#iFrameEditor").contents().find('body').css("backgroundColor",backgroundColor);